# add session in vb.net and use it in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, vb.net, session

This is how I assign session in vb.net

```
Dim CurrentSession As HttpSessionState = HttpContext.Current.Session
CurrentSession.Add("ExtendTimeLimit", 2)
```

inside javascript file

```
var ExtendTimeLimit = '<%=Session["ExtendTimeLimit"]%>';
```

problem is, when I alert ExtendTimeLimit, it is showing "*<%=Session["ExtendTimeLimit"]%>*" itself instead of number 2

Answer (score 0):

I end up using ajax

```
function ExtendTimeLimit() {    
    var result = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "Landing.aspx/ExtendTimeLimit",
        data: {},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data, e, jqxhr) {
            result = data.d.value;
        },
        error: function (data, e, jqxhr) { alert("ERROR=" + data.responseText); }
    });
    return result
}
```

and my backend

```
Public Shared Function ExtendTimeLimit() As ReturnGeneric
    Dim result As Boolean = True
    Dim value As Integer = 0
    Dim CurrentSession As HttpSessionState = HttpContext.Current.Session

    value = CurrentSession.Item("ExtendTimeLimit")

    Return New ReturnGeneric With { _
             .result = result, .value = value _
                        }
End Function
```